# kotlin jooq(3.9.3 commercial trail) generator oracle date to timestamp

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp, jooq

I need covert date column in oracle11 db to timestamp type in Java

so I set customtype and forcedtype in jooq-config.xml as same as https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/reference/reference-data-types/data-types-oracle-date/

generating table classes are all ok but Java project compiling failed with errors like:

```
no suitable method found for createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<java.sql.Date>,org.jooq.tdetails.tables.ApplicationChecklist,java.lang.String,org.jooq.impl.DateAsTimestampBinding)
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>,java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T,U>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Converter<T,U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,T,U
        (argument mismatch; org.jooq.impl.DateAsTimestampBinding cannot be converted to org.jooq.Converter<T,U>))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T,U>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Binding<T,U>) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
        inferred: java.sql.Timestamp
        equality constraints(s): java.sql.Timestamp,java.sql.Date)
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T,X,U>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Converter<X,U>,org.jooq.Binding<T,X>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,T,X,U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T,U>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Converter<T,U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T,U>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Binding<T,U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T,X,U>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Converter<X,U>,org.jooq.Binding<T,X>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,X,U
        (argument mismatch; org.jooq.tdetails.tables.ABC cannot be converted to java.lang.String))
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: compiling will be zero-problem when I use jooq generator without forcedTypes section in jooq-config.xml, so my code is totally correct

Comment: Can you post: 1) The DDL of your table, 2) The code generation configuration, 3) Your custom data type bindings

Comment: CREATE TABLE "TEST"."ABC" 
   ( "REF" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
 "NAME" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE),
 "CREATED_TS" DATE
   ) ...

Comment: <!-- Use this flag to force DATE columns to be of type 
   <dateAsTimestamp>true</dateAsTimestamp>
   
   <!-- Define a custom binding for such DATE as TIMESTAMP columns -->
   <forcedTypes>
  <forcedType>
    <userType>java.sql.Timestamp</userType>
    <binding>org.jooq.impl.DateAsTimestampBinding</binding>
    <types>DATE</types>
  </forcedType>
   </forcedTypes>

Comment: the reason is cant find the suitable implement for createField here: createField("CREATED_TS", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.DATE, this, "", new DateAsTimestampBinding());